# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException

Tags: android

I am building my android project, i got this error in my project. What should i do to get rid of this exception.

[image: []

This is my gradile file.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your app + the libraries have exceeded 65K method limit. Check here for more info http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Please copy paste your files, don't take screeenshots. Your error actually says "Multiple dex files define". Just search that phrase and you'll get lots of hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
defaultConfig{
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

in your build.gradle file.

Check if under libs/ there is some .jar. If yes, are they support-libraries ?
Exclude all under libs commenting this:

```
// compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Comment: I don't think the dex limit was reached. The error says "Multiple dex files define (class)", meaning that class was compiled more than once

Comment: Yes, at this point, maybe the problem is something inside libs directory.

Comment: After i add this in to the gradle file it make other error              Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/app2night/utils/crud$AsyncResponse.class

Comment: try to build the project with gradlew build --info

Comment: yes, it is working perfectly after i change the minSdkVersion